# Laravel Single User Data In A Multichained Distant Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

I have three models as per the code below.I have a problem of returning a single savings data for authenticated users. Any help will be highly appreciated.
I want a low like this:

```
$savings =Savings::client()->client_users()->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

**Savings Model**

```
class Savings extends Model
{
   
    public function client()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Client::class, 'id', 'client_id');
    }

}
```

**Client Model**

```
 class Client extends Model
    {
       
        public function client_users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ClientUser::class, 'client_id', 'id');
    }
    
    }
```

**Client User Model**

```
class ClientUser extends Model
    {
       
    public function user()
       {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
        }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```php
$user = Auth::user();

return Savings::whereHas('client.client_users', function ($query) use ($user){
    $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
}])->get();
```

Comment: Am getting an error @Maik Lowrey :Expecting a statement.Is that query complete?

Comment: @kevinotieno can you dump the result of the query? instread return push the result to a var and dump it. then share the result, pease.

Comment: Worked @Maik Lowrey.Thanks men

Comment: @kevinotieno Cool!  Can you voteUp and accept this answer please?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the above error. Thanks @Maik Lowrey

```
 $user = Auth::user();
    
$savings= Savings::whereHas('client.client_users', function ($query) use ($user){
                $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
            })->get();
            return response()->json($savings);
            //return response($savings);
```